# Tcl: Compare instances of a class

Tags: oop, tcl

I'm writing a method to compare two objects of the same class. The second object is passed in as an argument. The method starts by calling a private method `CalcValue` on the current object, that if neccessary (only need to do it once) calculates the numerical value of it and puts it in it's private variable `value`.

How can I do the same thing for the object sent in as an argument? How do I access that object's private `CalcValue` method, and later access it's private `value` variable? Should I make the method public and write a public access method for the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which object-oriented framework you used, so I assume [incr Tcl]. You will need to make the `CalcValue` method public if you want the second object to access it. Below is an overly simplified example that illustrate how to access your method:

```
package require Itcl

itcl::class Thing {
    method CalcValue {} { return 999 }
    method compare {otherThing} {
        set myValue [CalcValue]
        set otherValue [$otherThing CalcValue]
        # Do something
    }
}

# -------- MAIN: Create two instances and compare --------
Thing thing1
Thing thing2
thing1 compare thing2
```

If `CalcValue` is private, then the call `$otherThing CalcValue` will fail.